# Read keyboard input and mouse

Tags: linux, ubuntu, input, keyboard

I want to read keyboard and mouse inputs under Linux Lubuntu x64.

The characters and movements i get from the input need to be sendt to another Linux computer over lan.

I dont need absolute mouse coordiantes.

I herard of X11 but this is only for one window. 
Is there an easy way to get all this inputs on a global stage?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you ask? What kind of application are you coding? A window manager?

Comment: You should understand more about X11. Is your remote machine a Linux system?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are running a desktop (not a plain console), i.e. using an [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) server (so coding an X11 *client* application).

<sup>Please understand that the X11 server is running in the desktop or laptop connected to your physical LCD screen and physical keyboard and mouse. So X11 servers are *not* remote, but local and physically close to your eyes. X11 client applications could be remote but often are local.</sup>

<sup>Your real goals are not clear to me.</sup>

You need to learn a lot more about the [X Window System core protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol). You could grab the mouse and/or keyboard and use the *root window* - i.e. the entire screen (so get events for it). It looks like you want to code some part of a [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager).

Read also more about conventions like the [Extended Window Manager Hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html)

In practice, you surely want to use some toolkit like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/). Perhaps [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/) is well suited for your needs (which I don't understand well).

Perhaps improving an *existing* window manager and desktop environment is more realistic. Take advantage of and contribute to existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) related to your goals.

Be aware that [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29) might replace X11 in a few years.

PS. It might mean many months (or years) of work. But I am not sure to understand your goals

#### addenda

if you just need to send keypresses and mouse movements to a remote machine, consider `ssh -X` (google for [X over SSH](http://vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html)), or use some remote X11 application (i.e. set `DISPLAY=desktop:0` on the remote Linux machine and start an X11 client app there), or perhaps make your software on the remote machine become a specialized web server (by using some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)) and use the browser of your desktop.

It looks like you want to make your Linux desktop (or laptop) work like an [X terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_terminal). It is possible, but today (in 2014) it is probably a bad idea. You probably want your web browser to be local, and perhaps even the [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) suite. Make your desktop at least a (more or less) [thin client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client); if the remote machine and application does not have an X11 client library, see [Vnc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnc)

Comment: I need to send the pressed keys and mouse movements to another pc connected via lan.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain that. Can't you just use `ssh -X` ?

Comment: What operating system and application runs on the remote "another" PC ?